# Why accessing out of bounds not producing any error in my code?

Tags: c++, iterator

This is my function, I have run with `-std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra` with `clang` and `gcc` on `godbolt`;

both compilers did not produced any errors;

function returns `0`, when empty needle; returns `-1` when needle not found and returns `index` of first occurrence when match.

```
int strStr(string haystack, string needle) {

        if ( needle.empty( ) ) return 0;

        std::size_t n_len = needle.size();

        if( needle.size() > haystack.size() ) return -1;

        int index = 0;

        for ( auto it = haystack.begin(); it != haystack.end(); ++it )
        { 

            std::cout << std::string( it, it + n_len ) << std::endl; 
            if ( std::string( it, it + n_len ) == needle ) return index; // hear also
            //if ( !*(it + n_len ) ) break;
            index++;
        }

        return -1;

    }
```

I know I can get the results using `find` or `substr`;

I have tested with below, it should produce error, when I access out of bound, but no errors;

```
int main()
{
    
    std::cout << strStr( "aabaaaababaababaa", "bbbb") << std::endl; // prints -1
    std::cout << strStr( "hello", "ll") << std::endl; // prints 2
    std::cout << strStr( "mississippi", "issip") << std::endl; // prints 4
    std::cout << strStr( "ab", "a") << std::endl; // prints 0
}
```

Thank you for your time and assistance;

Comment: _"it should produce error, when I access out of bound, but no errors;"_ Why? You are responsible for it. If you want the check, do the check. If others want performance instead of the check, they skip the check.

Comment: thank you, but I have tested same code `leetcode` platform, it produced `runtime` error; on `godbolt`, it did not;

Comment: You forgot to link with the address sanitizer, then you'd get your error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it should produce error, when I access out of bound

No.

The behaviour of accessing an array out of bounds is undefined. There is no guarantee that you would get an error.

> but I have tested same code leetcode platform, it produced runtime error

There is also no guarantee that you would not get an error. There are no guarantees whatsoever.

Comment: thank you, but I have tested same code `leetcode` platform, it produced `runtime` error

Comment: @pvc Undefined behavior is not defined. It can produce a runtime error, format your hard drive, order a pizza or seemingly work correctly.

Comment: @pvc Why ask a question if you're going to ignore the answer?

Comment: @pvc Undefined behaviour is just that, undefined. C++ can be particoulary nasty in hiding bugs in your code. And then they will appear later, on a production environment you don't have access to. "With great power come great responsability". C++ has great power, but you are the responsable one :O

Comment: I will accept the answer, I was wonder, `godbolt` did not showed me error and `leetcode` showed me. that's all. now I know, If I link `address sanitizer`, I may get an error